# can't get data from array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

i am trying to get data from array of object in angular :

structure of my code :

```
storegeArray: any [];
```

1. fill all field in array "-" :

   ```
    this.storegeArray = new Array(100).fill("-");
   ```
2. push data into array in specific id:

   ```
      this.storegeArray[data.vehicle_id] = {x: location[1], y: location[0]};
   ```
3. save array (storegeArray) in local storege:

   ```
    localStorage.setItem("coordinates",this.storegeArray);
   ```

To here every thing work fine.'

```
console.log(this.storegeArray)
```

output :

```
(100) ["-", "-", "-", {…}, "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]
0: "-"
1: "-"
2: "-"
3: {x: 33.8953628, y: 35.4906471}
4: "-"
5: "-"
6: "-"
7: "-"
8: "-"
.......
```

Work fine i have data in id = 3 id of data.vehicle_id

In global case i have multiple data in different indice in array so i use this method to get :

```
const myArrayFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('coordinates');
if (myArrayFromLocalStorage) {
    for(let i=0; i<myArrayFromLocalStorage.length; i++){
      if(JSON.stringify(myArrayFromLocalStorage[i] != "-")){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(myArrayFromLocalStorage[i]));
      }
    }
}
```

output:

```
 "-"
 ","
 "-"
 ","
 "-"
 ","
 "["
 "o"
 "b"
 "j"
 "e"
 "c"
 "t"
 " "
 "O"
 "b"
 "j"
 "e"
 "c"
 "t"
 "]"
 ","
 "-"
 ","
 "-"
 ","
 "-"
```

What i try to do is fetch in array to see data (object) not "-" and get this data (object) that mean get x and y .

What i do wrong?

Comment: Use this : const myArrayFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('coordinates');)

Comment: i receive this error : ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) @TusharShahi

Comment: @lampardbre just clear your localStorage, as it is filled with non-json format right now (caused by previous wrong implementation). Also if there is no data in localStorage yet, `getItem` will return null, so that `JSON.parse` will fail, see how you can do it safely in 4th step of my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you keep the data for vehicle by an id, it's better to use an object instead of an array. Then you wouldn't need to check if it is `-` or not.

1. `this.storage = {};`
2. `this.storage[data.vehicle_id] = {x: location[1], y: location[0]};`
3. `localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(this.storage)); // to save the data`
4. `const dataFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data') || '{}'); // to get the data from localStorage`

Comment: i use array because data must change after getting new coordinate so for each car i have a position into array and after this i want to display it using marker.

Comment: You can update data in object as well. I just see no point of having an array which you filter from empty values instead of keeping only what you need

Comment: Don't forget to clear your localStorage before testing, as you have corrupted data there currently

Answer (score 4):

Issue that I found here are listed below.

Save array (storegeArray) in local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem("coordinates", JSON.stringify(this.storegeArray));
```

Always store a string value in `localStorage`

Also while fetching from `localStorage` parse it to valid JSON

```
const myArrayFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('coordinates'));
if (myArrayFromLocalStorage) {
    for(let i=0; i<myArrayFromLocalStorage.length; i++){
      if(myArrayFromLocalStorage[i] != "-"){
        // JSON.stringify is not needed here. You can directly compare to string
        console.log(JSON.stringify(myArrayFromLocalStorage[i]));
      }
    }
}
```

Try a sample here.
**NB:** I have used a mock storage variable since there is some issue in using localStorage in Sandbox editor.

```js
const storegeArray = new Array(100).fill("-");
storegeArray[10] = {x: 10, y: 10}
// localStorage.setItem("coordinates", JSON.stringify(storegeArray));
const mockStorage = JSON.stringify(storegeArray);
// const myArrayFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('coordinates'));
const myArrayFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(mockStorage);
if (myArrayFromLocalStorage) {
    for(let i=0; i<myArrayFromLocalStorage.length; i++){
      if(myArrayFromLocalStorage[i] != "-"){
        // JSON.stringify is not needed here. You can directly compare to string
        console.log(JSON.stringify(myArrayFromLocalStorage[i]));
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: i receive this error while using JSON.parse : ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @lampardbre can you add the structure of data stored in localstorage. I have added a mock code here.

Comment: thank you @Nitheesh , this work also but answer of mr. yuriy is so good and easy to do.